# How to list files using dos commands?

Tags: dos

I need to list the names of the files and store it in as text file!

What I did is, I used the following dos command

```
 x:\xyz> dir *.* > files.txt
```

what this does is that, it stores the names of the files present in directory xyz as well as size, time and date of the files!

How to get only the names of files?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try `dir /b`, for *bare format*.

`dir /?` will show you documentation of what you can do with the `dir` command. Here is the output from my Windows 7 machine:

```
C:\>dir /?
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
              Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
               L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
  /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
  /C          Display the thousand separator in file sizes.  This is the
              default.  Use /-C to disable display of separator.
  /D          Same as wide but files are list sorted by column.
  /L          Uses lowercase.
  /N          New long list format where filenames are on the far right.
  /O          List by files in sorted order.
  sortorder    N  By name (alphabetic)       S  By size (smallest first)
               E  By extension (alphabetic)  D  By date/time (oldest first)
               G  Group directories first    -  Prefix to reverse order
  /P          Pauses after each screenful of information.
  /Q          Display the owner of the file.
  /R          Display alternate data streams of the file.
  /S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
  /T          Controls which time field displayed or used for sorting
  timefield   C  Creation
              A  Last Access
              W  Last Written
  /W          Uses wide list format.
  /X          This displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file
              names.  The format is that of /N with the short name inserted
              before the long name. If no short name is present, blanks are
              displayed in its place.
  /4          Displays four-digit years

Switches may be preset in the DIRCMD environment variable.  Override
preset switches by prefixing any switch with - (hyphen)--for example, /-W.
```

Comment: Unfortunately the /B bare command and the /W and /D bare sorted by column switches do not work together.  I no of know way to suppress the summary and yet get the data in column order easily in DOS.

Answer (score 25):

If you just want to get the **file names and not directory names** then use :

```
dir /b /a-d > file.txt
```

Comment: If you want to filter for an specific type for example xml: dir *.xml /b /a-d /s | sort > files1.txt